# Heroku dont specify PORT on deploy

Tags: javascript, mongodb, heroku, deployment, continuous-deployment

My index.js:

```js
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8453;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Server in listening on port: " + PORT));
```

But, in deploy logs:

```
Running build (yarn)
yarn run v1.22.4
$ node src/index.js
Server in listening on port: 8453
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the log when you are running the code locally. Heroku logs looks different.

Answer (score -1):

What's up!

So, Heroku don't accept `.env` files, so, on the project config, you can set "Config vars", the config vars is the .env/process.env from Heroku